# Date Formatting in C++ Code Templates in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans for my C++ programming.

Would like to create the following code template for C++ source file and header file:

```
/**
 * Name:      %<%NAME%>%.%<%EXTENSION%>%
 * Author(s): %<%USER%>%
 * Date:      %<%DATE%>% 
 * Revision:  1.0
 */
```

Above NAME, EXTENSION, USER and DATE are default code templates provided by Netbeans. Where do I find this list in Netbeans? Also, the default result of DATE is MMM DD, YYYY format, e.g. February 29, 2012. Is it possible to customize the format to DD-MMM-YYYY (e.g. 29-Feb-2012)?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for PHP, it should be the same in C++.

```
<?php
  <#assign licenseFirst = "/** ">
  <#assign licensePrefix = " * ">
  <#assign licenseLast = "*---------------------------------------------------- ">
  <#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">
   * ${date}
   * File: ${nameAndExt}
   * Encoding: ${encoding}
   * Project: ${project.displayName}
   *
   * Author: Rob Haag :: rob@mydomain.com
   *
   **/
?>
```

[Reference](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic38387.html)

Comment: `${date}` just returns `${date}` - looks like the format is `%<%DATE%>%` now - this doesn't work at all for me.